# Why can't Scala infer the types from implicit evidence

Tags: scala, type-inference

I've tried this and it fails with *error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$29) => x$29.sum)*.

Can someone please explain why this happens? Is this just that Scala's type inference is not powerful enough?

```
object HelloStackOverflow {
    implicit class Repro[T](val iterable: Iterable[T]) extends AnyVal {
        def foo[A, B, Z](bar: Iterable[B] => Z)(implicit evidence: T <:< (A, B)) =
            bar(iterable.map(_._2))
    }

    List(("a", 1), ("b", 2)).foo(_.sum)
}
```

(using Scala 2.10)

Comment: `List(("a", 1), ("b", 2)).foo((a : Iterable[Int]) => a.sum)` works quite happily, so I'd guess that it's an inference problem.

Comment: Keep in mind the fact that type inference in Scala is performed one parameter list at a time, from left to right. Types known or inferred in one argument list can guide or constrain type inference in subsequent argument lists but not the reverse.

Comment: @Impredicative, my point was that I don't think specifying the type explicitly is needed because it's already defined by the implicit evidence.

Comment: @RandallSchulz, if your comment here was an answer, I would accept it over Regis's answer below.

Comment: I was not particularly certain it was the answer in this particular case, so I couched it as a "reminder" and put it in a comment. Until I saw @Impredicative's comment (which appeared while I was initially writing it up as an answer, actually), I was about to drop it entirely...

Comment: @RandallSchulz in regards to the statement "type inference in Scala is performed one parameter list at a time, from left to right", does it mean that even though the types `A` and `B` are inferred in the evidence type list, it is too late, because they were needed before in the list on the left ?

Comment: http://pchiusano.blogspot.cz/2011/05/making-most-of-scalas-extremely-limited.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well this is because "The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known" (Scala Language Specification 8.5).

When a method takes an anonymous function, scala uses the fact that it knows the type of the parameters to let the caller omit the types of the anonymous function's parameters (letting you write something like `x => x+1` instead of `x: Int => x+1`, or `_.sum` instead of `x: Iterable[Int] => x.sum`. This is one of the nice applications of inference in scala. But obviously, this requires to know the exact expected type of the anonymous function in the first place, which is not the case here: the argument to the anonymous function `bar`  is of type `Iterable[B]`. `B` is a free type variable that cannot in any way be inferred from earlier parameter lists (there is **no** previous parameter list in method `foo`).
So there is simply no way that the type of `B`  in the anonymous function `(_.sum)` can be inferred, which triggers an error as knowing the exact type is mandated by the spec.

This is pretty logical. In scala, an anonymous function is just (like any function) an object. Creating an anonymous function means instantiating a generic class (that extends `Function*`), where the types of the function's parameter are encoded as type parameters of the `Function*` class (read it again, I promise this sentence makes sense). It is simply never possible to instantiate any generic class without fully specifying the type parameters. Functions are no exception.

As Impredicative showed in a comment, explicitly specifying the type of the anonymous function's parameter fixes the compile error:

```
List(("a", 1), ("b", 2)).foo((a : Iterable[Int]) => a.sum)
```

Or even:

```
List(("a", 1), ("b", 2)).foo((_.sum):Iterable[Int] => Int)
```

But in your case, it appears simple to fix the issue without having to explicitly specify the type of the anonymous function:

```
object HelloStackOverflow {
    implicit class Repro[A,B](val iterable: Iterable[(A,B)]) extends AnyVal {
        def foo[Z](bar: Iterable[B] => Z) =
            bar(iterable.map(_._2))
    }

    List(("a", 1), ("b", 2)).foo(_.sum) // works like a charm
}
```

Maybe the reason why you used a single type parameter `T` (instead of parameters `A` and `B` as in my example above) with an evidence that `T <: (A, B)` was that in your real code you have other methods in class `Repro` that do not require `T` to be a pair. In this case, just create another implicit class `Repro2` with a `T` type parameter, and migrate these other methods there. You don't **need** to put all your enrichments in the same implicit class.

Comment: So to sum up what you wrote, the reason this doesn't work is because inference works only one parameter list at a time. That makes sense in terms of language implementation, but why would it make sense in terms of the theory behind the language?

Comment: Type checkers are specialized theorem provers. Theorem provers generally have serious tractability issues. This may be seen as an expedience, but it may also make more programs tractably type-checked than if inference were done "globally" (across the entirety of a method's parameters). There may be a better reason, but I'm far from familiar enough with the underlying theory to say.